# How can I Generate Setup Installation in Rad Studio?

Tags: delphi, c++builder, rad-studio

What files must I add while building the installation file in Rad Studio using Advanced installer? When I chose the project file, I launched the file created with Advanced Installer, but it says that:

> `file_name.bpl` missing

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't build with runtime packages (`Project->Options->Packages->Runtime packages->Link with runtime packages` is `False`), then you only have to distribute your application executable (.exe).

If you build with runtime packages (`Project->Options->Packages->Runtime packages->Link with runtime packages` is `True`), you have to include those packages when you distribute your application executable (.exe). This requires at a minimum that you include the VCL and RTL packages (vclXXX.bpl and rtlXXX.bpl, where `XXX` depends on the specific version of RAD Studio that you're using).

Depending on what your application does, you may also have to include other runtime packages in your installer. You can find the list of packages that your application needs by looking at the runtime package list in `Project->Options->Packages->Runtime Packages->Runtime packages` (click the `...` button to open the dialog).

For more information, see the RAD Studio documentation topic [Deciding Which Runtime Packages to Use](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Deciding_Which_Runtime_Packages_to_Use).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find a list of names of the packages used from the menu at `Project/Information for YourApplication` This list should be available once the project has successfully compiled and linked.

Even more useful may be the `Project/Deployment` menu item.  This item is designed to actually deploy your application and its files to a remote machine using paserver, and perhaps could be used to do that in the process of making your installation file.

However, the big advantage of `Project/Deployment` is that it lists not only the name of each file, but also the Directory where that file can be found.

It looks to me like there may be files under `Project/Deployment`, such as localization language files, that might not always be needed, so I would cross-check `Project/Deployment` (which shows the Directory) with the `Project/Information for YourApplication` list.  However, `Project/Deployment` is where I would look to find the directory where the missing `file_name.bpl` that Advanced Installer needs can be found.